# Waiting for template render in Meteor, inconsistent

Tags: templates, meteor

Been scratching my head on this, so here's the simplest way to view it - I'm using this:

```
Template.today.rendered = function() {
    console.log(this.firstNode.children.length);
};
```

Simply to try and get the count of items that are *supposedly* rendered. The template looks like:

```
<template name="today">
    <div class="todaySlider">
        {{#each dayOfWeek}}
            {{> singleDay}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>
```

and if it's of any importance, singleDay looks like:

```
<template name="singleDay">
    <div class="day {{isCurrent}}">
        <h2 class="date">{{date}}</h2>

        {{#each items}}
            {{> item }}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>
```

I'm trying to wait for all the "singleDays" to render, however that count I'm logging is usually different on refresh. I'll get anything from 0 to the correct value, and I don't understand why. This seems to be the right place to call it, I fear that maybe the double "each" is too slow?

I've tried timers (which I honestly shouldn't) and even DOM Mutation Observers (which seem like overkill) but surely there is a pure Meteor approach to this, any ideas?

Comment: I'm actually surprised that this would ever return anything other than 0. The helpers should fire after the `rendered` callback, so prior to that your `each` will not have anything to iterate over and your template will be empty apart from the initial `div`. I think a more important question, is why you need this count.

Comment: It's not the count that I need specifically. What I'm actually doing is trying to activate a class on the "last item", but I used the count to see if it actually finished rendering every ".day" or not. If it comes out to anything less than the "real total", it's not useful for me.

Comment: This theme comes up a lot in meteor: "I want to do something special for the item". The problem is that it's unclear what the "last" one really means in a list with dynamically updating items. How bad would be if you applied the class to whichever item happened to be the last at any given time?

Comment: Not useful. As the names imply, these elements are "days", I'm trying to set "today" (always last) to be active. Currently, it might set some day "in the middle" as active, or not set one at all (as well as, occasionally, set the right, latest day). It doesn't have to be by order necessarily, they do have IDs, but I need all the ".day"'s to be rendered first.

Comment: Argh!  I've been reading many similar questions about how to execute some javascript after the template is rendered, with no satisfactory answers.  The ".rendered" function seems to have the confusing and unsatisfactory meaning of "created in the DOM, but contents not populated".  (Am I right?)  Shouldn't there be a simple callback that is called when your template's content are completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template.rendered happens when the template is rendered, but that doesn't mean there'll be any data in it.

I'm pretty sure you'll need to do this inside a helper.

each helpers don't have to return cursors, they can also return an array.  If the number of "singleDays" is short, you could send an array to the template instead of a cursor.  It's kind of ugly, and there might be a better way to do this, but I think this will work.

```
Template.today.helpers({
    dayOfWeek: function() {
        var days = DaysCollection.find({}).fetch();
        if (days[days.length - 1]) days[days.length - 1].isLast = true;
        return days;
    }
});
```

I assume {{isCurrent}} is where you add the extra class that you're talking about.  If so, just have the isCurrent helper look for this.isLast to be true.

Comment: Sweet. This does work, although I occasionally get a "Exception in template helper: .dayOfWeek@http://192.168.13.13:3000/client/controllers/app.js?4017ddaba475696ff017a70cf74dda7911bf28c5:126:9", that line being "days[days.length - 1].isLast = true". Everything still works, just pops up in console. I'll wait to see if any cleaner solutions are suggested before marking this as answer!

Comment: If the template runs before the collection is ready, days[i] will be undefined.  Gotta check to be sure that it exists before setting a property to true.  I edited the line to add that.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like what is happening here is that the template is being rendered before the Mongo collection is sent to the client.  To be more specific, meteor renders your template as fast as possible, which means that it has no concept of 'waiting' for any data to be sent from the server to the client.  Therefore, if you place anything indirectly regarding database queries inside of a non-reactive call (Template.rendered), then it will execute with the data as `undefined`.

I'm assuming your `dayOfWeek` helper looks something like this:

```
Template.today.helpers({
  daysOfWeek: function () {
    var today = CollectionName.findOne();

    return today.daysOfWeek;
  }
})
```

(Or maybe you are using the router to pass the day directly to the template)

Either way, within your router you need to wait for the Mongo collection item to be sent to the client before any rendering takes place.  If you are using Iron-Router, you simply have to 'wait' for your data/subscription.

More information can be found here: https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#wait-and-ready

If you are still using autopublish, then you can replace the subscription with your database query.